# *Filter for image with Padding->None doesn't work properly on array

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, filtering

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier, persisting through 11.0.1.**

---

There's a number of `*Filter` for image processing in *Mathematica* and they're also supposed to work on array, according to the document. However, they seem not to work properly when `Padding -> None` option is added, for example:

```
lap = LaplacianFilter[#, 1, Padding -> None] &;
```

When the 1st argument of `LaplacianFilter` is an image, `Padding -> None` works as expected:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
ImageDimensions@img
(* {223, 164} *)
lap@img // ImageDimensions
(* {221, 162} *)
```

but when it's just an array, it doesn't:

```
lap@ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{-3.21096 + 3.21096 None, -1.52658 + 1.52658 None, -3.21096 + 3.21096 None},
>  {-1.52658 + 1.52658 None, 0., -1.52658 + 1.52658 None}, 
>  {-3.21096 + 3.21096 None, -1.52658 + 1.52658 None, -3.21096 + 3.21096 None}}
> ```

The supposed result is `{{0.}}`. Apparently `LaplacianFilter` has just treated `None` as a plain expression.

I haven't done a thorough test, but it seems that all the `*Filter`s for image processing have the same issue and `*Filter`s for signal processing like `BandpassFilter` is not influenced.

Is this a bug? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRI has confirmed to xzczd that this is a bug.

The former here is a sloppy workaround, I prefer the second method.

### Reroute with Image@

This works as expected on `Image[]`, so converting to image temporarily to process works:

```
lap = ImageData@LaplacianFilter[Image@#, 1, Padding -> None] &;
lap@ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]
```

`{{0.}}`

```
RepeatedTiming[lap@RandomReal[1, {20, 20}];, 2]
```

> `{0.00078, Null}`

### Use Padding->"Fixed"

This works faster as it doesn't require the image to be rendered:

```
lapfix = LaplacianFilter[#, 1, Padding -> "Fixed"] &
RepeatedTiming[ArrayPad[lapfix@RandomReal[1, {20, 20}], {-1, -1}];, 2]
```

> `{0.00028, Null}`

This gives the same result:

```
SeedRandom[1]
a = lap@RandomReal[1, {20, 20}];
SeedRandom[1]
b = ArrayPad[lapfix@RandomReal[1, {20, 20}], {-1, -1}];
a == b
```

> `True`

Comment: What's the definition of `lapold`?

Comment: @xzczd Just how you defined `lap`, I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Hmm… then I should say this comparison doesn't make much sense. `lapold` doesn't give the expected result anyway :) .

Comment: @xzczd You're right, it is superfluous. No way of knowing how fast it would run if that did work.

Comment: @xzczd So probably not a bug, but still an absent feature that one would expect to work.

Comment: WRI has confirmed the issue ("As you clearly have pointed out, the data form should also be parsed properly by the LaplacianFilter function. I have checked and confirmed the issue and have passed along the report to our developers."), I think it's safe to call it a bug.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for letting me know, I'll edit the answer.